# Beginning Web Development with Sinatra: Communicating mouse clicks to the server side

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra

I have a game board (checkers board) that I composed of table and td items. I need to be able to get the coordinates of the squares the users click on to the server-side. The squares all have id's (e.g. A4 and E7) I just need to get those clicks back to the server. Its pretty easy to capture the clicks using JQuery, but I'm not sure what to do with them then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to be new to web development and concepts of HTTP requests and responses, instead of starting with jQuery click handling, I think you should simplify your approach (and then gradually learn more advanced concepts such as AJAX):

Let your board be a table (`<TABLE>`) of links (`<A>`) which the user would click (skip Javascript altogether for start). The links would be in the form of `<A HREF="/click/A4" />` and the click on them will immediately perform an HTTP request to the server.

In Sinatra, you would have a handler:

```
get '/click/:field' do |field|
  # process the click here and return altered table
end
```

And that should be enough for you to start.

Answer (score 1):

Should be easy...

Listen to the click event on the TD element.  When click read the ID attribute " $(this).attr('id');".  Send an jquery ajax post to your server side with the relative data (id, etc..).

Brian =)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to find out how to ajax a square id to the server, but that should be simple with jquery.
So send your query with a `put` to: `/board/update/a4`

However, on the server end you will need a put route like this:

```
put '/board/update/:id' do
  square = params[:id]
  #now you have your id in square and you can do whatever you need to do with it...
end
```

(You can name your route whatever you like, this is just an idea.)
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Checkers is 64 squares, each square in one of three states, so - without using cookies - you can use javascript on the browser to create your state - 64 characters that are like 'br_bb___...' for black, red and blank, then send that 64 char string along with the clicked square. The server then sends back a new state, which the local js uses to display the squares.

Use a route as shown in the other answers.